# Custom Backend Login Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to create an extension that creates an entirely new backend login using 2 Factor Authentication. Where and how do I tell TYPO3 that it should not load its own backend login form but mine instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your login in your ext_localconf.
See: https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/openid/blob/master/ext_localconf.php#L49

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these two TYPO3 extensions which provide 2FA already do what you need so you don't have to reinvent the wheel:

- https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/authenticator
- https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cf_google_authenticator

At least they can give you some inspiration.